# Ошибка при установке MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

Ввожу команду `sudo apt install mysql-server` и начинается установка, в ходе  установки возникают ошибки:

```
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2421/fd/1023: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2544/fd/5: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2544/fd/6: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2544/fd/7: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2544/fd/8: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2544/fd/9: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2544/fd/10: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2544/fd/11: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2544/fd/65: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2544/fd/67: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2544/fd/1023: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2617/fd/6: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2617/fd/7: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2617/fd/8: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2617/fd/9: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2617/fd/10: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2617/fd/11: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2617/fd/12: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2673/fd/4: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2673/fd/6: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2673/fd/7: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2673/fd/8: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2673/fd/9: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2682/fd/6: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2682/fd/7: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2682/fd/8: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2682/fd/9: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2682/fd/10: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2682/fd/11: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2682/fd/12: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2682/fd/16: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/2682/fd/17: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/3254/fd/1023: Отказано в доступе
Не удалось выполнить функцию stat для файла /proc/3308/fd/1023: Отказано в доступе
```

Comment: Попробуйте от rootа

Comment: так вроде sudo и выполняет команду от рута

Comment: Невсегда так бывает

Comment: А когда машина перезагружалась последний раз?

Comment: На самом деле проблема эта уже давно и машина часто перезагружается. Рядом с линуксом стоит винда, если важно